# SSL configuration between CloudFront and Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront

I've been trying for hours to configure the following architecture in eu-west-1 (Ireland):

Internet HTTPS ---> Route 53 ---> CloudFront ---> Elastic Beanstalk

I did the following:

- Created an SSL certificate through ACM using the following domains xyz.com & *.xyz.com
- Created an Elastic Beanstalk App with HTTPS ON pointing to the SSL Cert above.
- Created a CloudFront distribution with the origin pointing to the Elastic Beanstalk URL xxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com and at the moment of adding the SSL Certificate, I couldn't choose to use the one created in the eu-west-1 region so I had to create another SSL cert pointing to xyz.com & *.xyz.com in us-east-1 (N. Virginia)
- Created the appropriate A Alias records in Route 53 pointing to my CloudFront distribution, xyz.com & *.xyz.com since Ill be supporting multiple subdomains.

Now, whenever I visit my site at xyz.com, 50% of the time works and 50% of the time I get the following message:

```
ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
CloudFront attempted to establish a connection with the origin, but either the attempt failed or the origin closed the connection. 
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
```

I'm not sure what am I doing wrong, from what I've read from tons of other answers here and in AWS's forums, might be a problem with the HTTPS connection but I don't understand why sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't, I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I don't know why.
I also find it strange that I can't use the same SSL certificate from us-east-1 in my EB application and viceversa with the SSL certificate from eu-west-1. I don't know much about SSL so perhaps I can't use 2 certificates pointing to the same domain?

EDIT: Also when using HTTP, it always redirects to HTTPS (using CloudFront) and always work, the only problem is when using HTTPS directly.

Thanks.

Comment: The issue is not with using certificates in different region..since CF is a global service, the certificate must be in us-east-1 region. I'd say check the alternate domain cname configuration of the CF and refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-alternate-domain-names.html

Comment: Done that, but still I keep getting an error, in my CNAME config in CloudFront I have xyz.com and *.xyz.com. I keep getting 504 using HTTPS, HTTP works and redirects to HTTPS properly.